# Add tiptool to a brush function chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Right now i have a brush function and two lines. I could add tiptool without brush function but since i have brush now, it wont focus anymore. And also i have two lines, so its hard to choose a appropriate tiptool. I wanted to add the tiptool only on the upper margin. I am new in javascript. Anyone could help me with it? Thank you so much
[image]

```js
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 40
  },
  margin2 = {
    top: 430,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%e/%Y %H:%M").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
  x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
  y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
  y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
  xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(x2)
  .on("brush", brush);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .defined(function(d) {
    return !isNaN(d.power);
  })
  .interpolate("cubic")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.power);
  });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
  .defined(function(d) {
    return !isNaN(d.power);
  })
  .interpolate("cubic")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x2(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y2(d.power);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


d3.csv("pvdata2.csv", function(error, data) {

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "pvdate";
  }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.pvdate);
  });

  var sources = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: d.date,
          power: +d[name]
        };
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([d3.min(sources, function(c) {
      return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
        return v.power;
      });
    }),
    d3.max(sources, function(c) {
      return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
        return v.power;
      });
    })
  ]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  var focuslineGroups = focus.selectAll("g")
    .data(sources)
    .enter().append("g");

  var focuslines = focuslineGroups.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return color(d.name);
    })
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  var contextlineGroups = context.selectAll("g")
    .data(sources)
    .enter().append("g");

  var contextLines = contextlineGroups.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line2(d.values);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return color(d.name);
    })
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("height", height2 + 7);

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 45)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Power (kW)");



});

function brush() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.selectAll("path.line").attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.values)
  });
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  focus.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}

// Active point element
var activePoint = svg.append('circle')
  .attr({
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
    r: 5,
    'pointer-events': 'none'
  })
  .style({
    stroke: 'none',
    fill: 'red',
    'fill-opacity': 0
  });
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```